# how to run query on dataset?

Tags: c#

i have Dataset that contain any database.

how to run any query on this dataset ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a DataView:

```
var view = new DataView(dataSet.Tables("TableName"));
view.RowFilter = "ColumnName LIKE '%something%'"

foreach (var row in view.Rows)
{
    // do something
}
```

or LINQ:

```
var results = from row in dataSet.Tables("Table").AsEnumerable()
              where row.Field(Of String)("ColumnName").Contains("something")
              select row;

foreach (var row in results)
{
    // do something
}
```

Google should suffice for a question like this...

Comment: thanks for the help, so i see that i need Moderator ? i cant sort for example the dataset without Dataview ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I believe you can use Linq To Objects to query this dataset:

```
var results = (from r in mydatasetvar.AsQuarieable() .. )
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688086) for more info

Alternatively, you can loop through the tables, rows and columns of the dataset.